# into magento, I create new customer form from mobile and how to insert its value into customer table?

Tags: magento

I want to insert some information of customer into all customer tables from outside form but I am not able to find out, when I create new customer from magento then how much value in table insert and what is name of table ? so that I able to  insert same values(field) from other form into database. 
Please help me and suggest me how to solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SQL is going to be a pain, use ORM rather:

```
require PATH_TO_MAGENTO_FOLDER . '/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$newCustomer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$newCustomer->setFirstname('Foo')
            ->setLastname('Bar')
            ... // Set all the various details here
            ->save();
```

Doing this via direct SQL would put you at risk for future upgrades, third party extensions etc.

User data in Magento is strung out between the `customer_entity_*` tables, and adding new data to the system will require you to grab each of the column definitions  (from `eav_attribute`) and place the data appropriately.

**Edit as per comments**

To create the address entity, you'll need to do the following:

```
$address = Mage::getModel("customer/address");
$address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
    ->setFirstname($customer->getFirstname())
    ->setMiddleName($customer->getMiddlename())
    ->setLastname($customer->getLastname())
    ->setCountryId('US')
    //->setRegionId('1') //state/province, only needed if the country is USA
    ->setPostcode('90210')
    ->setCity('Beverly Hills')
    ->setTelephone('123')
    ->setFax('123')
    ->setCompany('Company')
    ->setStreet('Street')
    ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
    ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
    ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

try{
    $address->save();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Hi moose ,Thanks for my help ,I am able to insert some customer field  such as firstname, lastname ,email ect But  its Street ,City ,Country ,State/Province,zipcode and Telephone are not inserting into database. Please suggest me how to solve it.

Comment: I've added the solution for the address entity model.

Comment: Thanks for reply and I have used this code but I got following error (Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mindct5p_sta`.`sta_customer_address_entity`, CONSTRAINT `FK_STA_CSTR_ADDR_ENTT_PARENT_ID_STA_CSTR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `sta_customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DEL)' in /home/mindct5p/public_html/STA/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0 /home/mindct5p/public_html/STA/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228):)

Comment: Hi moose, Please suggest me why this error is occurring ? and how to solve it ? Thanks

Comment: Hi moose,My problem have solved with your help so thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got sorted. Please don't forget to choose this as selected answer if it resolved things for you.